# Finding polynomial coefficients(Java)

Tags: java, math, fft

I have `N-1` (`N` is a power of 2) numbers `a1,a2…aN-1` in the world of mod `p` (where `p` is a large prime number)

My goal is to find the sum of all possible `k`-groupings (exactly `k` of the numbers multiplied together mod `p`) but I'm not given any of the values. Instead, I'm given `p`, `r` and `N` values from the below equation.

`for all 0 <= j < N, (rj+a1)(rj+a2)…(rj+aN-1)`

I also know the following

`rN ≡ 1 mod p`

For all `1 <= j < N`, `rj != 1 mod p`

Summation from `j = 0` to `N -1` of `rj ≡ 0 mod p`

So far I've realized the following

If we say the input multiplication results `= y` and use `N = 4` as an example, when foiled out I get the equation

`yj ≡ r3j + b1r2j + b2rj + b3`

where `bk` is the sum of all possible `k`-groupings (the answer I'm looking for)

I also know that I have point value form (`rj, yj`)

So far everything I've tried (multiplying by `P-1(x)` matrix, Lagrange Interpolation) hasn't given me a useful answer, I'm out of ideas as to how to calculate what those coefficients are, which means I can't even begin to code a program for this.

The example I have to work from gives the following information(`a1 = 6`, `a2 = 13`, `a3 = 30` but I shouldn't need that information to solve it)

```
p = 53

r = 30

y1 = 17

y2 = 24

y3 = 44

y4 = 0
```

and my output should be

```
b1 = 49

b2 = 12

b3 = 8
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I know FFT might be involved because we were learning about it at the time, but I can't figure out a use for it that doesn't leave me with imaginary numbers.

EDIT: Fixed Formatting